# Query with my view (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, view

I have to create a view that displays select table names and their number of columns.

I've managed to create a view that displays one table and its number of columns. But when i add more tables to the view, i get an error on that line (`AND table_name = 'Finance', 'Sales', 'HR'`).

I also get this error:
`ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

My view's below, any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE VIEW NameAndColumns AS
SELECT table_name AS Department, COUNT(*) AS NoOfColumns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'Coursework'
AND table_name = 'Finance'
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Comment: Perhaps see IN()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid syntax:

```
AND table_name = 'Finance', 'Sales', 'HR'
```

You have to be *specific* about the logic you're implementing.  In this case, your logic when spoken aloud would be:

> And table_name equals Finance, or table_name equals Sales, or table_name equals HR

Wrap your various `OR` conditions into a single condition for your `AND` clause:

```
AND (table_name = 'Finance' OR table_name = 'Sales' OR table_name = 'HR')
```

Which, by the way, could be refactored into:

```
AND (table_name IN ('Finance', 'Sales', 'HR'))
```

Comment: ...which is why they invented IN()

Comment: @Strawberry: Good point, that had just occurred to me too.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure it had ;-)

Comment: @David Worked like a charm. Super simple Operator, wish i had knew about it earlier